# How to export GridView to excel using OpenXML in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I know people asked similar questions already. But the solutions are not what I am looking for. For my case, our GridView holds at least a million of records. In addition, our customer doesn't like the warning message from excel 2007. Because of the warning message, we cannot use the most common way that uses GridView.RenderControl(). So we decided to try OpenXML. But from all the sample codes I have found, to create an excel file using OpenXML, it seems that you have to loop each row&column of the GridView and write to each cell of an excel file. It will take a good amount of time. Does any one know if there is better/faster solution? Also, we cannot use third party DLLs because of security reason. Thanks.

Comment: you need to change the file type in your code from `.xls` to `.xlsx` I can post an example on how to do this using `ClosedXML` however  `1 million` rows is a lot from my understanding Excel has a 69k limit in regards to number of rows.. but I can post what I do and you can test it .. I currently do this and it works like a charm.. also it's not that difficult not to mention there are other ways to save data datable to Excel.. I have post some here as well on Stackoverflow

Comment: also can you show us what you have tried since you stated that what you are looking is not in any of the previous postings / solutions that you have found

Comment: @MethodMan : your sample code snippet would be useful. I would like to point out that starting with version 2007, Excel Worksheets contain 1048576 rows, so the task can be completed as described in OP. Best regards,

Comment: I will post something that I am doing currently with ClosedXML hold one sec

Comment: @MethodMan: thanks and regards,

Comment: @AlexBell if the OP is familiar with creating a separate static class `Utils Class` and understands what I have posted, this works using ClosedXML I have also just tested this in a small web app Cheers..!

Comment: @MethodMan: interesting solution, thanks for sharing: upvoted. Best regards,

Comment: It's an extension I wrote taken from the Example given on the ClosedXml web site.. and I wrote the RemoveHtmlSpecialChars method because from the web for some reason there was strange data being returned from our legacy Oracle Database and It was easier to add the call regardless feel free to use this.. it will save you tons of headaches and you can test it based on any datatable that you pass it..

Comment: Why are you exporting a GridView and not the underlying data? Ex, the `DataTable` or `IEnumerable<Model>` that you bound do it?

Comment: I have rolled back your question to its original incarnation. Do not put solutions into your question.

Comment: Then how am I put solution and ask further questions?

Comment: If you edit your question as described in the close reason, then we can reopen the question and you can put your solution. However I don't think you'll be able to achieve that as your question was just too broad and not an example of the kind of question that should be here. I suggest you review the information in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) prior to asking any new questions. If you're still confused on what should and shouldn't be asked here, then [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is a great place for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what do u mean my question is too broad. There exists question like How to export GridView to excelsheet? posed here. It's pretty much the same as mine, just my question is I can't use the GridView.RenderControl because of the Excel 2007 warning message. So I decided to use OpenXML. I am looking for any suggestion to improve performance issue that OpenXML has.

Comment: It's too broad because it's too open ended. You didn't provide your code, you basically said "someone write some code that exports a GridView to Excel for me." That's too broad. If someone has made an attempt and shown in their question how they're exporting their code and they're having an issue with it, that would be on topic. Your question does not do that, and thus it's too broad.

Comment: I didn't say someone write some code for me. I was going to post my code there. Maybe I shouldn't say "solution". But you rolled back my code.

Comment: You did ask for someone to write your code for you. You said it right in the title, and you didn't provide any code showing your issue. I didn't closely look at the code you posted in your edit, just the fact that you said it was the solution. So if you're saying that was the not the solution code but was instead what you started with then you can edit that into your question if you want and I won't roll it back. Be clear about what the code is, and make sure you properly format it. And realize that *almost always* your questions on Stack Overflow should have some code *from the beginning*.

Comment: How to export GridView to excel using OpenXML in c#? Can someone please provide me some code?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's too broad. As I commented before, you should read the Help information and if you're still confused then go to Meta and ask about it.

Answer (score 1):

here is a method that I use to Export DataTable to Excel I created a class  `public static class Extensions` to house these methods

```
internal static void ExportToXcel_MyDataTable(DataTable dt, string fileName, Page page)
{
    var recCount = dt.Rows.Count;
    RemoveHtmlSpecialChars(dt);
    fileName = string.Format(fileName, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_hhmmss"));
    var xlsx = new XLWorkbook();
    var ws = xlsx.Worksheets.Add("Some Report Name");
    ws.Style.Font.Bold = true;
    ws.Cell("C5").Value = "MY TEST EXCEL REPORT";
    ws.Cell("C5").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Black;
    ws.Cell("C5").Style.Font.SetFontSize(16.0);
    ws.Cell("E5").Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    ws.Range("C5:E5").Style.Font.SetFontSize(16.0);
    ws.Cell("A7").Value = string.Format("{0} Records", recCount);
    ws.Style.Font.Bold = false;
    ws.Cell(9, 1).InsertTable(dt.AsEnumerable());
    ws.Row(9).InsertRowsBelow(1);
   // ws.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Gray;
    ws.Columns("1-8").AdjustToContents();
    ws.Tables.Table(0).ShowAutoFilter = true;
    ws.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
    DynaGenExcelFile(fileName, page, xlsx);
}
private static void DynaGenExcelFile(string fileName, Page page, XLWorkbook xlsx)
{
    page.Response.ClearContent();
    page.Response.ClearHeaders();
    page.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xlsx", fileName));

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xlsx.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.WriteTo(page.Response.OutputStream);
    }
    page.Response.Flush();
    page.Response.End();
}
```

If you have Html / special characters in the DataTable this method will remove them replacing the row data with string.Empty

```
/// <summary>
/// Remove all HTML special characters from datatable field if they are present 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dt"></param>
private static void RemoveHtmlSpecialChars(DataTable dt)
{
    for (int rows = 0; rows < dt.Rows.Count; rows++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
        {
            dt.Rows[rows][column] = dt.Rows[rows][column].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I could use ClosedXML either. I found a solution from this site http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm, which is very helpful. Basically it use OpenXMLWriter to write to an excel file. But I noticed my memory usage is still up to 20%, I wonder if there anything I could do to improve it.

Comment: How come you can't use ClosedXML.. if you can use OpenXML you can surely use ClosedXML I have noticed no memory issues when using ClosedXML..it's hard to know what memory issues you are having if you do not show any existing code in regards to how you are using it..